# Stop the pipeline when stage is unstable

Tags: jenkins-workflow

I have a Jenkins build pipeline created using workflow plugin.  At the beginning the pipeline runs a gulp  build inside of the docker container and then archives test results using the following code

```groovy
step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: 'build/test-results/*.xml'])
```

In the following steps I package up the artifacts and ship them to the binary repository.

When unit tests are not passing Jenkins understands the build is unstable and marks it yellow.   However it still continues with subsequent steps in the pipeline.  Is there any way make the pipeline stop when unit tests are failing?

Comment: How are you calling gradle? Using an `sh` step?

Comment: Oops,  my bad.  The pipeline that's failing is the front end build using  Gulp / node.   It's run through sh in the docker container.  The backend gradle builds handle this situation correctly.

Comment: Ok. Then there is nothing to do at Jenkins side but at Gulp side. The call to gulp CLI needs to return a proper error value to have the `sh` step failing correctly - I guess it is actually returning 0 even being not finishing successfully.

Comment: But Jenkins does detect that the build has become Unstable.   All I need is for the pipeline not to continue once the build becomes Unstable

Comment: As I said Jenkins just interprets what the shell is returning, so probably Gulp is not returning what you want. I just found this blog post which seems related to what you want: http://derrickbowen.com/blog/content/stop-gulp-build-unit-test-failure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the **JUnitResultArchiver** will cause this condition to be true when the build is unstable:

`currentBuild.result != null`.

If I remember correctly it sets it to **UNSTABLE**, but it is enough to check that is different than null.

So you could do something like

```groovy
step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: 'build/test-results/*.xml'])
if (currentBuild.result == null) {
    //contintue with your pipeline
} else {
    //notify that the build is unstable. //or just do nothing
}
```

Comment: Be care when to use `currentBuild.currentResult` and when `currentBuild.result`. See [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/WEBSITE-364)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do at Jenkins side but at Gulp side. The call to gulp CLI needs to return a proper error value to have the sh step failing correctly.
Jenkins just interprets what the shell is returning, so you juts need to make Gulp to return a fail when tests fail (see [this blog post](http://derrickbowen.com/blog/content/stop-gulp-build-unit-test-failure), it seems to achieve exactly that).